# SSIS sync two tables on different servers

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am a starter of SSIS. If you have any guidance, please be specific. Thank you.
I am trying to sync two tables on two different servers.

Table A on Server A(60k data) and Table B on Server B(60k data).
there are mainly 3 things:

1. Add new records where they are in Table A not Table B.
2. Update records where Table A and B both have and update them.
3. Delete records where they are not in Table A, but in B

There are no primary keys in both tables. But two columns together can mostly help to find certain records(there are duplicates each table, but not many)

http://www.rad.pasfu.com/index.php?/archives/150-Insert,-Update,-and-Delete-Destination-table-with-SSIS.html

I've tried to use this guy's method to figure it out, but failed. I tried this way on two sample tables which has a couple of lines of data, successful.

On real tables, I set Column A and B as SortKeyPosition 1 and 2 since I have to use them together.

Full outer join at Merge Join

Conditional Split for New Records as below:

(!ISNULL(S_Column A) && !ISNULL(S_Column B)) && (ISNULL([D_Column A]) && ISNULL(D_Column B))

Delete Records as:

(ISNULL(S_Column A) && ISNULL(S_Column B)) && (!ISNULL([D_Column A]) && !ISNULL(D_Column B))

As a result, I got 34k data for new records and 0 records for delete ones.
I've tested on SQL for the real result, 1000+ for new records and 600+ for deleting ones. 60k around needs to be updated. I don't know what causes this problem and how to fix it.

Updating: I personally used a OLE DB Command to write SQL command replacing all data(some of the data don't need to be updated) after conditional split(assuming I am doing write before). I am looking for better solutions for updating too.

Hoping to get helped! Thank you again and early happy holiday!

Comment: You will usually have significant problems if the source and destination do not have any combination of fields that function as actual common  unique identifiers. Also, when working between servers, I frequently find that explicitly copying one table to a temp table on the other server will speed things up significantly.

Comment: this is not an SQL problem but a logistics one. you MUST have a unique way to identify rows, and that is the very nature of a unique ID column. Even if you come up with a combination of columns, performance would be bad without an unique index.

Comment: I've used sql command to select distinct data from two source tables. It seems my problem is on the merge join part. Not knowing the reason, the data comes through is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Try the following steps:

```
COPY table from ServerA to a working table on ServerB
Handle Duplicates by theoretical index
    Are these 'duplicates' differentiatable by adding additional fields? 
        If so, add those fields to the indexing.
        If not, assume that all of these rows on ServerB will end up looking like one row from ServerA
DELETE rows from B that do not match rows from A
UPDATE rows in B where the keys match in A but data differs (it is worthwhile to compare the data and only update if the data is actually different).
INSERT the new rows from A
DROP or TRUNCATE the working table.
```

Comment: The DELETE / UPDATE / INSERT operation order is actually significant, since this minimizes the number of index lookups that must be performed.